# Windows 7 Mouse Freezes Intermittently

Tags: windows-7, mouse, freeze

I am running Win 7 64 Professional with an Core i7-3770s an 16GB RAM on Gigabyte GA-Z77X-D3H motherboard. My Logitech M515 mouse (as well as an older mouse I tried to make sure) freezes for several seconds from time to time. I have tried without success

- updating drivers
- switching to different USB ports
- disabling USB and RAID controllers
- setting energy settings to high performance
- uninstalling old device drivers no longer used

On another forum someone suggested running DPD latency checker, which showed that every ~2-3 seconds something kicks the latency up to > 4000µs, but I haven't figured out what program is responsible for that - disabling all but the most essential device drivers had no effect.

Has anyone here had this problem and solved it?

Comment: Have you tried removing the Logitech drivers and running the mouse with the base Windows drivers?

Comment: Is anything else sharing the usb hub?  Have you checked your batteries?  Are you sure it's the mouse-freezing and not the whole computer?  Have you looked at what's running the background?

Comment: I tried uninstalling the Logitech drivers - no freezes up till now, but they were infrequent before. The USB hub has several other devices connected but I had the same problems when I had only the unifying receiver connected. It is only the mouse, as music or games run just fine while the mouse freezes, even accepting keyboard input. The batteries are fine. I have several programs running in the background (Dropbox, Google Sync, Firefox, Thunderbird) but freezes even happened with 95% CPU free.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please refer [here](http://forums.logitech.com/t5/Mice-and-Pointing-Devices/Disabling-the-Logitech-M515-couch-mouse-hand-sensor/td-p/650708) for a solution to this problem.
Its due to the hand sensor proximity and you can disable it in two ways.

In software (taken from hd42's comment):

Logitech offers the [ProxiTool](http://logitech.lithium.com/t5/Mice-and-Pointing-Devices/How-to-disable-the-Couch-Mouse-M515-hand-proximity-sensor/td-p/695502) to disable the proximity sensor

Physically - instructions taken from baptist's post in the thread linked above.

```
1. Remove cover over batteries;

2. Unscrew one screw;

3. Remove mouse cover;

4. Find green board with chip at the top of mouse;

5. Find wire connected to this board;

6. Lift white part of connector up and remove the wire (you will be able to plug the wire back if you want).

7. Enjoy
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but could you distill the main points here, and just reference the original post? It will better help others who have the same problem.

Comment: Thanks for your Link. I found the solution in that forum. Logitech offers the [ProxiTool](http://logitech.lithium.com/t5/Mice-and-Pointing-Devices/How-to-disable-the-Couch-Mouse-M515-hand-proximity-sensor/td-p/695502) to disable the proximity sensor. Since I did that, I haven't had this problem any more.

Comment: Downvoting until quality of this answer isn't improved.

Answer (score 0):

I was experiencing this as well, until finally the cursor stopped moving altogether. That helped me find the actual problem--there was a curly piece of lint obstructing the optical sensor. I guess the lint was shifting around as the mouse moved and occasionally blocked the sensor.

This has happened to me twice in the last couple of years, so it'll be interesting to see if this helps solve anyone else's problem.

Comment: I had a similar issue and it was driving me nuts.  I had a few, hard to see cat hairs that were in the well for the sensor and when I removed them and the mouse works perfectly again.

Comment: Unfortunately, my problem persists after thorough cleaning and existed from the day the mouse left it's package.

Answer (score 0):

I was experiencing occasional freezes and I think that was a problem with RAM. I don't really know what kind of magic Windows used, but it seemed to quietly recover from each stall after a few seconds without telling me anything.

Hit Start and run **Windows Memory Diagnostics**, after the computer restarts switch test to extended (that's the one that found errors) and let it run not 2 but 4 or so iterations. After I narrowed the problem to particular sticks, I have removed that pair and the problem went away with remaining sticks.

I'm using Logitech m570 and I'm actually curious if RAM was not the issue.